# Running tests from coverage.py vs running coverage from test runner

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, coverage.py

During the [Coverage.py with Ned Batchelder](http://pythontesting.net/podcast/coverage-ned-batchelder/) python&testing podcast, Brian and Ned briefly discussed that, if you need to run tests with coverage, *it is preferred to run tests from `coverage.py`* executing the `coverage run` as opposed to invoking a test runner with coverage. Why is that and what is the difference?

---

To put some context into this: currently I'm using `nose` test runner and execute the tests with the help of `nosetests` command-line tool with [`--with-coverage` option](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/cover.html):

```
$ nosetests --with-coverage --cover-html
```

Should I do it via the `coverage run -m` instead?

```
$ coverage run -m nose
$ coverage report
```

Comment: I don't know if this is correct (so I'm not posting it as an answer), but my gut guess is that if you use coverage directly, then you're concerned with coverage, and nose, and you don't have the additional dependency of the plugin. Less coupling, and one fewer version to track.

Comment: "invoking a test runner with coverage" -- You haven't been explicit about what test runner you're talking about (and perhaps they weren't on the podcast either -- I haven't listed to it).  I guess with the test runner case, you're trusting the test runner to start up the coverage machinery at the correct time (e.g. before importing the stuff to test).  If you invoke coverage directly, then you know that everything is set up to use coverage from the get-go and every line will be tracked as you want it to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I am uniquely qualified to answer this question :)

mwchase and mgilson have it right in their comments: using a plugin means you are depending on that plugin's behavior being correct and understandable.  In the name of being helpful, plugins will have their own logic that may have been the best idea when they were written, but the test runner and/or coverage.py may have changed in the meantime.  The plugins tend not to be as well-maintained as the other components.  If you can avoid them, you have one less thing to think about.

True fact: the reason I added support for .coveragerc configuration files in the first place was because I wanted to add features to coverage.py and didn't want to wait for plugin UIs to be updated to support them.

Comment: For some reason, most of the "how to use nose/pytest with coverage" command samples out there on the internet show how to use a runner with a coverage plugin not mentioning that you can also use `coverage run` and it is generally a better way. Thanks again!